# Can't play sound when app is in background mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, avaudioplayer

In Info.plist I added:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
...
```

I load the sound like this:

```
NSURL *urlFail = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/criticalSound.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
                    NSError *error;
                    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlFail error:&error];
                    [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
                    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
                    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
                    [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
                    if (audioPlayer == nil){
                    }else{
                        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
                        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
                        musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
                        if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
                        {
                            self.wasMusicAppOn = YES;
                            [musicPlayer pause];
                        }else{
                            self.wasMusicAppOn = NO;
                        }
                        [audioPlayer play];
                    }
```

This works fine when app is active.
But I have a location update when application is in background and from time to time (like when user pass 500m) I should play this sound.
So I put this code there.
Anyway problem is that sound plays when app is in foreground but doesn't work when it is in background.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you gone through this [Ray Wenderlich's Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've been able to tell, you must actually be playing sound while going into the background to be able to continue playing sound in the background.

Also, the description for `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` states that "Your audio is silenced by screen locking and by the Silent switch (called the Ring/Silent switch on iPhone)".

Comment: I need to start app and press home button putting app in background and after 20minutes I want to play sound, then hour after that, then two hours after that... you wan't to say that this is not possible?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think so. possibly you could use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` and play a silent sound continuously, but then you'd draw battery accordingly.

Comment: the way I understand the design of the frameworks this is something that should be done via local notifications. they can also take a sound to be played.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make couple of changes in plist file.

1) Set Required background mode to App plays audio

2) set Application does not run in background to YES.

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

Then, you need to write these much code in AppDelegate

Now, you can easily run audio while phone screen locks or in background.

It works fine for me. :)

for more please refer to [Playing Audio in background mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) and [Audio Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)